# Why and/or where is the nil value?

Tags: lua

I'm using geany to run this. The problem is, the console is returning that I'm trying to index a nil value but I don't know if it is in line 63, 80, or even in another line. I'm really a beginner in programming so I don't know and understand many things if you could keep it simple I would be grateful.

Here's the error message:

```
lua: TTC.Lua:65: attempt to index a nil vallue (field'?')
stack traceback:
 TTC.Lua:65: in function 'preenche_tabuleiro'
 TTC.Lua:82: in main chunk
[C]:in ?
```

Here's the code:

```
function cria_tabuleiro()
    return {{_, _, _}, {_, _, _}, {_, _, _}}
end
 
function pula_linha(_)
    for __ = 0, _ do print() end
end
 
function abertura_do_jogo()
    pula_linha(7)
    print("\t-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-")
    print("\t-      TIC-TAC-TOE      -")
    print("\t-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-")
end
 
function checa_OS()
    os.getenv("HOME")
    if home == nil then return "|", "--", " " end
    return "↓", "→ ", "."
end
 
function recebe_nomes()
    jogs = {}
    for _ = 1,2 do
        msg = ("Digite o nome do jogador numero %s: ")
        io.write(msg:format(_))
        table.insert(jogs, io.read())
    end
    return jogs
end
 
 
function imprimir_tabuleiro(T, SB, SD)
    abertura_do_jogo()
    pula_linha(2)
    print(string.format("\t\t    A B C\n\t\t    %s %s %s" , SB, SB, SB))
    for _ = 1,3 do
        io.write(string.format("\t\t %s%s", _, SD))
        print(table.concat(T[_], " "))
    end
    pula_linha(5)
end
 
function ler_jogada(JOGADORES, X)
    jogada = {}
    checa_jog = function(jog)
        coluna = string.byte(jog:upper()) - 64
        linha = tonumber(jog:sub(2))
        if coluna >= 1 and coluna <= 3 and linha >= 1  and linha <= 3 then
            return coluna, linha
        else
            print("Sua jogada foi invalida, tente novamente")
            ler_jogada(jogadores, X)
            end
        end
    pula_linha(2)
    io.write(string.format("%s, digite sua jogada (EX:B3, A2, ETC...) : ", JOGADORES[X]))
    table.insert(jogada, io.read())
    col, lin = checa_jog(jogada[1])
end
 
function preenche_tabuleiro(tabuleiro, POS_VAZIA, PECAS, jogadores, _, COL, LIN)
    if tabuleiro[LIN][COL] == POS_VAZIA then
        tabuleiro[LIN][COL] = PECAS
    else
        msg = "%s, voce tentou uma posicao ja preenchida. jogue novamente."
        print(msg:format(jogadores[_]))
        preenche_tabuleiro(tabuleiro, POS_VAZIA, PECAS, jogadores, _, ler_jogada(jogadores, _))
    return tabuleiro
    end
end
 
abertura_do_jogo()
SETA_BAIXO, SETA_DIREITA, POS_VAZIA = checa_OS()
tabuleiro = cria_tabuleiro(POS_VAZIA)
jogadores = recebe_nomes()
PECAS = {"X", "O"}
imprimir_tabuleiro(tabuleiro, SETA_BAIXO, SETA_DIREITA)
for _ in pairs(jogadores) do
    preenche_tabuleiro(tabuleiro, POS_VAZIA, PECAS[_], jogadores, _, ler_jogada(jogadores, _))
end
```

Comment: Running your code i got a different error (line 49: compare number with nil), can you add a method for reproducing your error?

Comment: Please add the error message to your question. If it's showing multiple line numbers, it's probably just showing the current state of the function call stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ler_jogada` does not return your `lin` and `col` values but you're using it here, as if it did:

```
preenche_tabuleiro(tabuleiro, POS_VAZIA, PECAS[_], jogadores, _, ler_jogada(jogadores, _))
```

`ler_jogada` sets global values:

```
col, lin = checa_jog(jogada[1])
```

so when you pass it as the last param to `preenche_tabuleiro` you will get `nil` values for `COL` and `LIN`

If you add a print before line 64, you can see the issue: `print(LIN, COL, lin, col)`

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but what should I do to make it work properly? I'm new at programming, even more to Lua.

Comment: either have `preenche_tabuleiro` return the values or use the globals you made `col` and `lin`